# Unable to extract "base 64" from svg drawn in canvas using foreignobject

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I'm using svg-to-image and get-canvas-context packages of npm. 
Without using foreignobject i can extract canvas to png image. But the main problem is I need foreignObject in my svg to fulfil the requirement.

```
var svgToImage = require('svg-to-image')
var getContext = require('get-canvas-context')

// set up a new Canvas2D
var context = getContext('2d', {
    width: 200, height: 200
})

var data = `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<style>
div {
    color: white;
    font: 18px serif;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" />


<foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">

<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,
porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam
erat volutpat.
</div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>`;

var View = svgToImage(data, function (err, image) {
    if (err) throw err

  // draw image to canvas
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

  // append to DOM
  var canvas = context.canvas
  window.a=document.body.appendChild(context.canvas)
// console.log(a.toDataURL('image/png'))
  // open a PNG image the user can Right Click -> Save As
  window.open(context.canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
})

export default View;
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? The code you post here is a slightly modified version of the example code of the svg-to-image library. If you just copy pasted the code and it didn't work, you're probably testing on a browser that does not support foreignObject, as stated directly below the example code. If that is the problem, can't you like, replace all the HTML nodes with their equivalent in SVG, `<text>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using 'svg-to-img' package in client side.
use same package on server side (node)

```
const svgToImg = require("svg-to-img");

svgToImg.from(svg).toPng({ width: dimension[0]/2, height: dimension[1]/2 })
```